# My Minecraft Skin isn't using the right model

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've noticed that when I login to Minecraft servers my skin is the classic model, even though when I adjusted it in the launcher I made sure it was 3px - **slim**.

I've tried;

- Using a different version
- Using a different skin and switching it to the same one

And yes, I have made sure that the skin is default 3px, and the reason it annoys me is because there are two black lines going down my skin's arms, and it just really bugs me. 
*Help*?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, and add the version you're playing (I'm not sure if the latter matters a lot, but it might)?

Comment: Delete the skin and re-add it